# Unable to run predict on batch using keras-yolov3 model

Tags: python, keras, yolo

I created a tiny yolo model using the code provided in https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/ 
I am unable to pass a batch of images where each has shape (416,416,3) to the created model.predict_on_batch() 
The error I see is this:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[0.5686275 , 0.5568628 , 0.5921569 ],
        [0.9411765 , 0.92941177, 0.96862745],
        [0.91764706, 0.9098039 , 0.9254902 ],
        ...,
        [0.62352943, 0.5921569 , 0.6156863 ],
  ...
```

What are the 3 expected arrays which this model expects to see?

Comment: could you provide an example code?

Comment: input_batch = load_images() 
# input_batch.shape = (2,224,224,3) since I have 2 images of dimensions (224,224,3)
When I pass this input_batch into model.predict_on_batch() I see the aforementioned error